# Take the Camera away from the Player in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

when my player gets destroyed, I want to take the camera (it's a child object of the player) and take it back to the hierarchy. But I don't know how to get the hierarchy's transform.

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")) // player collision with the obstacle
        {
            ReplaceCamera(); // Take the camera away from the player
            Destroy(col.gameObject); // Destroy the player
        }
    }

    void ReplaceCamera()
    {
        Camera.main.transform.SetParent(?); // Set the camera as a child of the hierarchy
    }
```

I just don't know what to pass in as a parameter for my ReplaceCamera method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting a transforms parent to `null` will place it in the root of the hierarchy,

```
    void ReplaceCamera()
    {
        Camera.main.transform.SetParent(null);
    }
```

Later when/if new player spawns you can add the camera back to the spawned player by setting the transform to be a child of the player, you can use this function to do both, which will set it to a player if you supply one.

```
    void ReplaceCamera(Transform player = null)
    {
        Camera.main.transform.SetParent(player);
    }

// Usage Examples
    ReplaceCamera(); // will send it to the root
    ReplaceCamera(player); // will send it to be part of the player again.
```